# Javascript - find highest value in an object of arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, max

I have an object containing arrays of objects. I'm trying to find the highest value of an object property, 'sortOrder' without manually iterating through the arrays and objects.

So my variable looks like this following:

```
const myObj = {
 people: [
   0: {firstname: 'Dave', lastName: 'Jones', sortOrder: 22},
   1: {firstname: 'Jane', lastName: 'Smith', sortOrder: 11}
 ],
 otherPeople: [
   0: {firstname: 'Jen', lastName: 'SomeLastName', sortOrder: 33},
   1: {firstname: 'ExampleFirstName', lastName: 'ExampleLastName', sortOrder: 12}
 ]
};
```

So I'd be trying to iterate through this to eventually find, in this case, the highest sortOrder of 33. Not necessarily the array index or the object containing it, just the number.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to have the `people` and `otherPeople` sorted by the sortOrder descending?

Comment: if you have them already sorted, then just return `sortOrder` of the first element in the array it will be the highest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) get the list of arrays
- Using [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), convert the 2d array into one
- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over this list while updating a `max`

```js
const myObj = {
  people: [ {firstname: 'Dave', lastName: 'Jones', sortOrder: 22}, {firstname: 'Jane', lastName: 'Smith', sortOrder: 11} ],
  otherPeople: [ {firstname: 'Jen', lastName: 'SomeLastName', sortOrder: 33}, {firstname: 'ExampleFirstName', lastName: 'ExampleLastName', sortOrder: 12} ]
};

const maxSortOrder = 
  Object.values(myObj)
  .flat()
  .reduce((max, { sortOrder = 0 }) => sortOrder > max ? sortOrder : max, 0);

console.log(maxSortOrder);
```

Answer (score 1):

(I had to slightly correct your input data: arrays don't include the index number as you're showing.)

Easiest to combine the two arrays in the object into one list and then use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to find the maximum:

```js
const myObj = {
  people: [
    {
      firstname: 'Dave',
      lastName: 'Jones',
      sortOrder: 22
    },
    {
      firstname: 'Jane',
      lastName: 'Smith',
      sortOrder: 11
    }
  ],
  otherPeople: [
    {
      firstname: 'Jen',
      lastName: 'SomeLastName',
      sortOrder: 33
    },
    {
      firstname: 'ExampleFirstName',
      lastName: 'ExampleLastName',
      sortOrder: 12
    }
  ]
};


let allPeople = [...myObj.people, ...myObj.otherPeople];

let max = allPeople.reduce((maxSort, person) => {
  return Math.max(maxSort, person.sortOrder)
}, 0));

console.log(max)
```

Comment: +1 for taking the *clean your data/(re-)organize your data then it's simple* approach. I too often fall victim to writing overly complex code to handle poor data choices, instead of fixing the root problem. (not that OP made a poor data choice in sample here, but data manipulation is a good solution for this problem anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You can order them by the highest sortOrder and then take the higher of the highest elements in each array:

```js
const myObj = {
  people: [{
      firstname: 'Dave',
      lastName: 'Jones',
      sortOrder: 22
    },
    {
      firstname: 'Jane',
      lastName: 'Smith',
      sortOrder: 11
    }
  ],
  otherPeople: [{
      firstname: 'Jen',
      lastName: 'SomeLastName',
      sortOrder: 33
    },
    {
      firstname: 'ExampleFirstName',
      lastName: 'ExampleLastName',
      sortOrder: 12
    }
  ]
};
Object.values(myObj).forEach(peopleArray => {
  peopleArray.sort((a, b) => b.sortOrder - a.sortOrder)
})
let maxValue = Math.max(myObj.people[0].sortOrder, myObj.otherPeople[0].sortOrder)
console.log(maxValue)
```

Comment: "If you have the array elements already sorted by sortOrder" I think your answer could be better if you take out the conditional and include the sorting as a necessary portion of the answer. As asked it isn't conditional / that's not extra information to the solution; its a distinct portion of it.

Comment: alright thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0):

```
const myObj = {
people: [
    {firstname: 'Dave', lastName: 'Jones', sortOrder: 22},
    {firstname: 'Jane', lastName: 'Smith', sortOrder: 11}
],
otherPeople: [
    {firstname: 'Jen', lastName: 'SomeLastName', sortOrder: 33},
    {firstname: 'ExampleFirstName', lastName: 'ExampleLastName', sortOrder: 12}
]};

let maxSortOrder = 0;
for (const value of Object.values(myObj)) {
    maxSortOrder = value.reduce((acc, { sortOrder }) => sortOrder > acc ? sortOrder : acc, maxSortOrder);
};

console.log(maxSortOrder); //33
```